# Fibonacci Mystery

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I saw this on a "numberphile" video and tried to prove it but couldn't do anything.

**Theorem:** Let $n \ge 2$ and $F_m$ is the $m^{\text{th}}$ number in the Fibonacci sequence. Then, if we look all $F_m$ ($m \ge 1$)  in modulo $n$, we will have a cycle. This cycle can only contain $1$ zero, $2$ zero or $4$ zero.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you missing a detail here? Are you saying that this holds *for any choice of $n$*, i.e. modulo *any* integer?

Comment: @FlybyNight It claims that $n\ge2$, but that's it...  (So not exactly any choice of $n$)

Comment: It's for any choice of n.

Comment: The existence of a cycle is easy, because there are at most $n^2$ possibities for two consecutive numbers modulo $n$.

Comment: What does a cycle mean in this context?

Comment: @Tobias: Cycle here surely means that Fibonacci sequence becomes periodic (a well known fact).

Comment: @Tobias It can only mean there is some $k$ so that $F_{k+j}\equiv F_j\bmod n$ for all $j$ sufficiently large.

Comment: @anorton I had taken the OP's assumption to be tacit.

Comment: The case when the modulus is a prime other than $2$ or $5$ (that can be just checked manually) is relatively straight forward. It follows from Binet's formula that we get a zero residue only once per period or every half period depending on the order of the Golden ratio in the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. I'm not ruling out the possibility that an open bottle of Lagavullin impairs my thinking though. With $n=5$ we seem to have four zeros in a period.

Comment: Note that when we reach zero, the sequence goes $\dots r, 0, r, r \dots$ so the repeat sequence (mod $n$) is $r$ times the original sequence. It is also known that $F_r|F_{kr}$ for positive integers $k$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen $p = 113$ has four zeros in the period. We have a zero when $\varphi^{2n} \equiv (-1)^n \pmod{p}$, so that leaves $1,2,4$ as possibilities.

Comment: @Daniel: At least we are counting it the same way! For some reason I thought that the order of $-\phi^2$ is either the period or half the period, because the period is the l.c.m. of orders of $\phi$ and $-1/\phi$. Some case escaped me. Exiting back left...

Comment: @MarkBennet Thank you, the first part of your observation was what I was missing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For the first part:** There are only finitely many possible choices for 
$$(F_{m-1},F_m) \pmod{n} \,.$$

Thus, there exists some $m < k$ so that

$$(F_{m-1},F_m) \pmod{n} = (F_{k-1},F_k) \pmod{n} \,.$$

Now, prove by induction that

$$F_{l} \equiv F_{l+k-m} \pmod n$$

**Alternate solution** If you know matrices, there is a simpler solution.

You know that

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
F_{m+1} & F_m \\
F_{m} & F_{m-1} \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^m$$

Now, by Lagrange Theorem,

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^k \equiv I_2 \pmod{n}$$

where $k$ is the order of $GL_2(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)$. Thus

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{m+k} \equiv \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^m \pmod{n}$$

**For the second part:** As mark pointed, if $F_k \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$ then $F_{k-1}=F_{k+1}= r \pmod n$ for some $r$. Then

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^k= \begin{pmatrix} 
F_{k+1} & F_k \\
F_{k} & F_{k-1} \end{pmatrix}= r I_2 \pmod n$$

thus, by taking determinants, we get $r^2 \equiv \pm 1 \pmod n$ and hence

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{2k}=  r^2 I_2= \pm I_2\pmod n$$
and hence

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{4k}= I_2\pmod n$$

thus, if $F_k \equiv 0 \pmod n$ then $4k$ is a period for $F_m \pmod n$, and from here the conclusion follows immediately (note also that $\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{2k}, \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{3k}, \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{4k}$ are all three diagonal matrices, thus have a zero inside).

**P.S.**(added) The reason why we get $1,2$ or $4$ is simple: if $k$ is the smallest positive integer for which $F_k \equiv 0 \pmod n$, then we showed that

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^k= r I_2 \pmod n$$

and $r^4 \equiv 1 \pmod n$. It is easy to show that the number of zeroes is exactly the order of $r \pmod n$.

Comment: You can also prove quickly that there exists **at least one** $0$ in the period: for $n>1$ the modded cycle always begins $1,1$, hence the cycle must end with a $0$ to get the recursion correct.

Comment: It seems like the real meat of this question is how to show the cycle has 1,2, or 4 zeros mod $n$.

Comment: @AWalker But how do you know that the $(1,1)$ pattern will recur? In general, even if there is a cycle, it could start with a sequence not part of the cycle.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen That follows immediately from the Matrix proof. If $k$ is as in the proof we have $$\begin{pmatrix} 
F_{k+1} & F_k \\
F_{k} & F_{k-1} \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^k=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0& 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ Thus $F_{k+1}=1, F_k=0 \pmod{n}$. Now what is $F_{k+2}$?

Comment: @Harald: The recurrence will work backwards as well as forwards. Thus the sequence is periodic, not just eventually periodic.

Comment: @user2566092 Added a solution to that too :)

Comment: @Jyrki: Ah, of course. Silly me.

Comment: This is VERY nice.